# Code=102 "Frame load interrupted" when I load a NSstring as a html Iphone

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, nsstring

I am developing an app for iphone/ipad that I have some problems with.

I am building dynamically a nsmutablestring with html code and loading as html to a uiwebview. I also load a local js file to this html page where I have some logical functions. 
In this html I got a form with a submit button at the end.

What I am trying to do is that at the moment the submit button is click, it will call a method that return a string back to the objective-c code. I have no problem with the javascript controlling the form. But when the submit button is click, the native code gives me

```
Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 "Frame load interrupted" UserInfo=0x6c60b20 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=file://
```

I have tried to redirect in js-function like window.location="myapp:custom:"+string; But I got the same problem. Even trying libraries like JSBridge api.

I suspect that is because I am loading a NSString to the webview that has the baseUrl the mainbundle path for loading the local js-file.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:string baseURL:baseURL];
```

Comment: What's is that string you give to loadHTMLString ?

Comment: Is html code. But I actually found out whats the problem is. The workaround with the fake url does not work with a input submit, but works with a input button. So it is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only had to change the input submit with a input button in the html code and works. So now I got the string from javascript back to objective-c.